# Django models save prohibited

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I'm new to Django, I'm tring to save an entry on the history model with the code below.

This are my models

```
class Actius(models.Model):
    id     = models.ObjectIdField()
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ric    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pais   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    index  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class History(models.Model):
    actiu  = models.ForeignKey( Actius, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    time   = models.DateTimeField()
    price  = models.FloatField(max_length=255)
```

What I'm tring to do

```
actiu = Actius.objects.filter(ric='EUR_USD').get()
print(actiu)
# output: Actius object (None)

entry = History(
        actiu = actiu,
        price = 12
)

entry.save()
print( actiu.history_set.all() )
# output
# ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'actiu'.
```

The `actiu` field i already created...
Why says it's not saved?

Comment: Seems your actiu object does not have id set ->  output: Actius object (None)

Comment: The reason of this error is because actiu is not saved to DB yet. Because `Assigning unsaved objects to a ForeignKey, GenericForeignKey, and OneToOneField now raises a ValueError.` 

However the thing that I don't get is that you already have Actius object and you are filtering it. I believe it will work if you do `actiu.save()` but this is not a good solution imho.

Where did you create the `actiu` exactly can you also share that please?
You should also check [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.8/#assigning-unsaved-objects-to-relations-raises-an-error)

Comment: Thanks, I thought that the id are created by default and I see that not

Comment: @OmerAlkin as I already mentioned he has saved object in database but he is missing id ( and without set id relations cannot be set  hence bit misleading error as this would normally happen if object does not have id yet)

Comment: So the proper way is probably to drop your 'id' field on Actius model. Django will provide one by default AND auto-populate it as you expect.

Comment: I'm usig mongodb and previously the Actius didn't had id. I don't know how to make an autoincrement with foreing key...
So I'm just creating manully an Id now.

@CedricDruck droping id field causes the same error